# Ubuntu 20.04 extremely slow - Zoom problem?

Tags: 20.04, dell, video, intel-graphics, zoom-meeting

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 (from scratch - not an upgrade) a week ago
still struggling with very slow video.  (even when no other applications is operating - just playing solitaire goes very slow. 
The cpu is working like crazy ...

I use Dell Inspiron 3580. with intel core i3-7020U. graphics - Intel Mesa HD Graphics 620

Update

The problem was not solved but worsened - and then  my computer refused to boot. I suspected hardware problem but the lab said it was software (well - no warranty applies ...:(
The disk was formatted, Ubuntu 20.04 re installed. and just to be on the safe side I rebooted after each and every application I installed. and lo and behold - immediately after my first Zoom meeting - everything went south once again.

again the cpu is overworking for no apparent reason and everything goes slow even when Zoom is not working..

Trouble is that nowadays I can't do without it.. (and choosing another video conferencing application is not up to me... )

Update:
I have reinstalled 18.04. Everything works just fine. I don't know what had happened but now I can do my proper work...

Comment: Considering you're specs it's like fitting an Aston Martn engine on a lexus. Consider a lighter version like Lubuntu

Comment: the computer worked well under 18.04. why would 20.04 be so much worse on my hardware?

Comment: I'd go with disabling animations `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations 'false'` `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.search-providers disable-external 'true'` at first, or installing a lighter desktop environment .

Comment: Switch to Xfce from Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing another kernel. I've a Dell Latitude 3490 with i7 and my performance was poor after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.

Then I installed the liquorix kernel and it worked.
I could not understand why the default kernel led to a slow computer, but liquorix solved it (I'm using the 5.7.0-10.1-liquorix-amd64)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advices I received.

As I mentioned - after giving up I rolled back to 18.04.

When 20.04.1 came in August I upgraded again - this time as an upgrade and not from scratch.

This time - although 20.04 is still somewhat slower than 18.04 - it is just that - "somewhat". not as slow as it was before.

I am not sure what was the reason for the extreme slowness that I had before but I suspecct it had to do with the disply - I downsized to 1368X768 - down from 1920X1080 - and I might have activated unwittingly the fractional scaling - which takes a lot of computing power.

Anyway - my machine is now usable... so thank you all